# What am I supposed to do with the blue signs appearing after a captain is killed?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

Everytime I kill a captain (or higher rank) there's a blue sign appearing on his body (the bow, sword or dagger).

Can I grab it? What is the use for it? I tried a few times to grab it (in wrath and regular world) without success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do they look like this?

[image]

If I'm not mistaken, those things are [runes](http://shadowofmordor.wikia.com/wiki/Runes).

Whenever you kill a nemesis, there is a chance that they drop a rune. You can upgrade your weapons with these runes.

Comment: Yes this is it!

After being able to access one out of combat (which tends to happen not to often in my case) A tooltip appeared telling me to press `Left CTRL`, on PC. The character then picked up the rune.

Comment: Good. I read that they stick around indefinitely (even after you die), so you should be able to collect the ones you left behind.

Comment: I'll have to find the last dozen I didn't pick up then. It's nice to know they'll stay in the world though!

Comment: On PS4 you have to press R1. Also a little tip: If you kill a captain who drops a rune and you are still surrounded by enemies, you can't pick it up instantly because the same button grabs enemies and picking up a rune has an animation of about 2 seconds. That's why I wondered at first how to pick up the runes. To pick it up, run away and have the mob follow you, hide until they no longer run after you and sneak back to the rune.

Comment: On xbox it's RB, which is also grab. I haven't had any trouble at all grabbing the runes instead of people, but I do always take a little step towards the run after it pops up. @JeffNoel they appear on your map too, so they'll be easy to find.

Comment: @JeffNoel Don't worry, they show up on the world map too

Comment: As @5pike said, they do seem to stay forever. I retrieved a rune that I forgot to pick up after restarting the game.